# SQL Server, swap dates in timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a DB table that two columns of type datetime, as per below

```
eventTime               timeStamp               Sequence
1970-01-13 17:14:50.000 2020-03-22 18:28:15.443 5575268
```

What I need to do is update the year in eventTime from the year in timeStamp, but leaving the time in eventTime untouched so I end up with

```
eventTime               timeStamp               Sequence
2020-03-22 17:14:50.000 2020-03-22 18:28:15.443 5575268
```

whats the best way to do this (I have about 600k rows I need to do this to...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add the difference in years between the `timeStamp` and the `eventTime` to the latter:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET eventTime = DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, timeStamp, eventTime), eventTime);
```

Comment: You can add `WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, timeStamp) <> DATEPART(YEAR, eventTime)` also.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows the addition of `datetime` values.  So:

```
update t
    set eventTime = convert(datetime, convert(date, timestamp)) + convert(datetime, convert(time, eventTime))
    where eventTime < convert(date, timestamp);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4872fff6191d843f6307b1f32c38d5c9) is a db<>fiddle.

You can also add the number of days:

```
update t2
    set eventtime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, eventtime, timestamp), eventtime)
    where eventtime < convert(date, timestamp);
```